# NFS slow after upgrading ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, nfs

Untarring software packages takes forever. It was much faster before upgrading to ubuntu 16.04. I have bumped up the number of nfs server daemons from 8 to 32 and have also mucked with `rsize` and `wsize` with very little difference.

*EDIT:*

my `/etc/exports`:

```
/shared-home  *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

Client `fstab`:

```
server:/shared-home /shared-home nfs _netdev,auto 0 0
```

Comment: What NFS protocol version is involved? Any use of the `sync` option?

Comment: @thrig I updated my question. We are thinking about using `async` in `/etc/exports`. I've read different things about this being safe vs unsafe. Any opinions on this? Right now our nfs is very slow so we are open to all options to increase performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `/etc/exports/` to `async` like so:

```
/shared-home  *(rw,async,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

fixed the issue for us.